# setting color to a comment's characters in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a cell in Excel from one range to another range's comment, while keeping its format (size, bold, color, italic...).

My piece of code works, except for color, which throws a Run-Time error '1004': 
Font size must be between 1 and 409 points.

Which is strange, because size works, and if I comment out color lines (') it works.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Function Comment_Format(ByVal Rg_Value As Range, ByVal Rg_Com As Range) As Comment
Dim i As Long, a As Long
If Rg_Com.Comment Is Nothing Then Rg_Com.AddComment
With Rg_Com.Comment
    .Text Text:=Rg_Value.Value2
    .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
End With

For i = 1 To Len(Rg_Value.Value2)
    With Rg_Com.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(i, 1).Font
        .Size = Rg_Value.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size
        'a = Rg_Value.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color
        'If a > 0 Then .Color = a    '  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< this line shows the error !!
        .FontStyle = Rg_Value.Characters(i, 1).Font.FontStyle
    End With
Next i
Set Comment_Format = Rg_Com.Comment
End Function


Sub test()
Dim com As Comment

Set com = Comment_Format(Range("a1"), Range("b1"))
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using a **Sub** rather than a **Function?**

Comment: just tried, same result (color not working).

Comment: by the way, it is very slow, so i tried to pass the Rg_Value in a variant variable, no success (it loses all formating)

Comment: It works find for me, using a short string with three colors. Are there any particular colors that make it fail?

Comment: i used the standar orange on one part of the text if i remember correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had better luck using **ColorIndex** rather than **Color** and coloring first:

```
Sub MAIN2()
    Call Comment_Format(Range("a1"), Range("b1"))
End Sub

Sub Comment_Format(Rg_Value As Range, Rg_Com As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    With Rg_Com
        .ClearComments
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Text Text:=Rg_Value.Text
        L = Len(Rg_Value.Text)

        For i = 1 To L
            .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex
        Next i
    End With

    For i = 1 To L
        With Rg_Com.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(i, 1).Font
            .Size = Rg_Value.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size
            .Bold = Rg_Value.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold
            .Italic = Rg_Value.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Which for me gave:

[image: pic]

**EDIT#1:**

There appears to be a bug in *Excel 2007 / Win 7* in the processing of **Color** with **Comments**

Comment: i use `.colorindex` now, and for troubleshooting, i added a `on error resume next`

Comment: Are you using **Excel 2007?**

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution and why a color line of code would rise a 'size' error.

I did like you, first color it all and then a second loop,

but added the autosize before the first loop (because my text is BIG) , then color loop,

then the 2nd loop (including size),

and then doing a second autosize=true because of course size changed !

i think its kind of like trying to select a cell in a hidden sheet, just applyed to comments

(the color property might rewrite every active pixel color but he cant 'read' a hidden pixel (being out of comment's shape size), am i making any sense to you?)

final code, working (any size of text):

```
Option Explicit

Function Comment_Format(ByVal Rg_Value As Range, ByVal Rg_Com As Range) As Comment

'Set Rg_Value = Range("A1")  'origin of the text
'Set Rg_Com = Range("b1")    'destination cell containing the comment

Dim i As Long   'simple loop counter
Dim ff As Font  'i used a variable for the long repeating garbage code (Rg_Value.Characters(i, 1).Font)
Dim L As Long   ' lenght of text (mine is 508 in my sample)

If Rg_Com.Comment Is Nothing Then Rg_Com.AddComment
With Rg_Com
    .ClearComments
    .AddComment
    With .Comment
    .Text Text:=Rg_Value.Text
        .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True  '<<< just to make all text visible in one comment, all chars having the basic size
    End With
End With

'On Error Resume Next

L = Len(Rg_Value.Text)

    For i = 1 To L
        Set ff = Rg_Value.Characters(i, 1).Font
        With Rg_Com.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(i, 1).Font
            .ColorIndex = ff.ColorIndex
        End With
    Next i


    For i = 1 To L
        Set ff = Rg_Value.Characters(i, 1).Font
        With Rg_Com.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(i, 1).Font
            .Size = ff.Size
            .Bold = ff.Bold
            .Italic = ff.Italic
            .Underline = ff.Underline
        End With
    Next i


Rg_Com.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True  ' <<< now chars of the comment's text already have different sizes, and i need to resize the shape

'On Error GoTo 0

Set Rg_Value = Nothing
Set Rg_Com = Nothing

End Function


Sub test()
Dim com As Comment
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False    'tryed to make it faster, but still uber slow (25 seconds for my 508     characters sample text)
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Set com = Comment_Format(Range("a1"), Range("b1"))
Beep            'wakes me up when the looping is over
Set com = Nothing

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
End Sub
```

[image]