# How do I refer to highlighted text in an Excel comment?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs when I press ctrl-d.  It should turn the selected text green and make it strikethrough.

However I want it to apply to selected text in a comment, not the text in the cell itself.

If I say:

```
Sub TaskFinished()
    With Selection.Font
        .Strikethrough = True
        .Color = Green
    End With
    MsgBox ("Ran macro!")
End Sub
```

it works for the text in the cell (color doesn't work but I can figure that out later), but only if the cell is selected (as opposed to being in F2 edit mode).

The message box only appears when I am not in edit mode.  Seems a macro can't even be triggered in edit mode at all?

Comment: Why don't you post your full code. The example you have is meaningless.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353024/setting-color-to-a-comments-characters-in-vba

Comment: But how do I get the size of the chunk of text that his highlighted while still editing the comment?

Comment: You can't  Vba will not run while in edit mode.

Comment: Is there a way to hijack keyboard shortcuts like ctrl-5 to have more functionality than just adding a strikethrough?  I'm able to strikethrough selected text while still in edit mode but to change color I'd have to do more stuff.

Comment: FWIW, the new (ish) [Threaded Comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.commentthreaded?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm1009072)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) feature allows VBA to run while the comment editor is open.  However I cannot find a way to interact with the editor, maybe someone else can

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
Sub TaskFinished()
   With Selection.Font
    .Strikethrough = True
    .Color = rgbGreen
  End With
MsgBox ("Ran macro!")
End Sub
```

'use rgb for color coding